# How to get information about origin of startup error messages?

Tags: neovim

Looks like there's an error somewhere in my init files (vimrc or one of several lua scripts) that causes an `E79: Cannot expand wildcards` error when vim starts up, but no other information to enable debugging it. Going over the whole config (and maybe plugins) is one option but there has to be a better way. It's particularly frustrating because I can't reliably reproduce it.

**Is there an option that enables stack traces or something similar ?** I'm not getting any extra info in `:messages`.

`NVIM v0.10.0-dev-597+gaa362a2af` compiled from source on Linux Mint 21

Comment: There is a debug mode `:help :debug` i think